# Do tasks use multiple threads? C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

If async/await is concurrently and does not use multiplet threads, then why when i run this does it say 15 threads in use?

```
await ReadFile("test.docx");

int number = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count;

Console.WriteLine(number);

async Task<Task<byte[]>> ReadFile(string file)
{
  var bytes = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(file);
  return bytes;
}
```

[image: Memory profiler]

[Detailed memory profiler 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs6Xc.png)

[Detailed memory profiler 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rosqL.png)

Comment: Just a note, you don't `await` the async method in your `async`-marked method. You should do that rather than returning a Task of a Task

Comment: What's the thread count before you call `ReadFile`?

Comment: the thread count is the same before and after regardless if i use await or not. it is only less if i have pure synchronous methods

Comment: *"the thread count is the same before and after"* - Then that is your confirmation that async/await does not use extra threads.

Answer (score 2):

> Do tasks use multiple threads?

**A general answer**: you can't tell. The fact that `Task` is in the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace and that `Task` has the `ConfigureAwait` to control on which thread should the continuation execute, you should be always prepared that spawning new thread(s) *may* happen.

**Concrete answer for `File.ReadAllBytesAsync`**: As this seems to be an IO operation it would make sense not to use use extra threads at all, but in fact, your observations are right: depending on the file size the [`InternalReadAllBytesAsync`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/File.cs,f266db58b0db4c05) implementation calls [`RandomAccess.ScheduleSyncReadAtOffsetAsync`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/RandomAccess.cs,ceeeb701f2d2286c) one or more time, which ends up [queuing](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/SafeFileHandle.ThreadPoolValueTaskSource.cs,74b2b442e61a54df) a `ValueTask` in the thread pool in every iteration.

Comment: is there a possible way to control this? as it is incrementally increasing memory usage in my application.

Comment: @DominicSmyth The use of threads or async/await won't be the cause of a memory leak. Make sure you're disposing of anything that implements `IDisposable`. Some reading on that: [Using objects that implement IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)

Comment: @GabrielLuci thats strange, when i do a memory profile it says the main leak is from overlapped data which is from system.threading

Comment: @GabrielLuci if you look at the memory profiler you will see its not unmanaged memory taking up most of the memory

Comment: @DominicSmyth: _"as it is incrementally increasing memory usage in my application"_ - normally it should not increase memory usage endlessly. However, thread pool can upscale itself if it runs out of free threads, which threads are not freed then. In your example this can happen for the first larger file. Reading more files concurrently may cause uncontrollable upscaling though, so in that case I suggest you to do 'manual' or sync reading (optionally on separate threads) so you can spare the pool threads and control resources better.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg it goes up to around 500mb after a day, i am reading one hundred files but only processing one at a time using async/await and task.whenall and it goes into the millions of files

Comment: Thread pool can be starved even by other operations, eg. when multiple long-runnig tasks are launched by `Task.Run` in the application/service. Maybe the safest if you go with a custom implementation using `Stream.ReadAsync`. It also uses the default scheduler (and thus the thread pool) but it will not queue multiple tasks if you await each `ReadAsync` calls until the whole file is read. Or just read the file sync and poll the cancellation token 'manually'.